# internet explorer caret browsing gets enable after every refresh

Tags: internet-explorer-8

i don't know what happend but on every window/tab i open, and on every refresh or link clicked- the caret browsing gets enabled automaticly

what is the solution for this?

--FIXED--

i enabled all active-x and for some reason that what happend so i reset the active-x settings

Comment: What is "caret browsing"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_navigation

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in tools, internet options, Advanced Tab, accessibility. This setting is only turned off temporarily if you press F7, you need to uncheck it to turn it off permanently.

Comment: you forgot to say the ADVANCED tab... but i have already tried that and it came back!

Comment: Corrected to add "Advanced Tab" to the path

Comment: Can you add that to your question, please